MDrivenDesigner-UMLModeling -> OCL For Accessing Link table data and writing it to another model with Link table
I have contracts table, that contains multiple products, there is a many-to-many relationship between contracts and products, this yields the link table [Contract-lineitem]: While converting a contract into a purchase order, I would like read all the products but also pick extra details from contract-lineitem table that are not contained in the products table: How do I go about this during the creation of the purchase order from contracts?

First create the purchase order:

Then iterate over the contract items and update purchase order items tables:

Check if product in the current contract exists in the newly created purchase order items

If not create it and return the newly created purchase order item in the view:

else update the existing products in the purchase order item with the correct details and return the updated record:
So here is what I have come up with, does anyone have a better approach?


(
  vCurrent_Contract.Products->collect(p|
    po.Products.add(p) -- add products to purchase order
    );
   --iterate over the contract items and update purchase order items
  vCurrent_Contract.ContractItem->collect(cItem | 
    let poItem = po.PurchaseOrderItem->select(i|i.Products=cItem.Products)->first in 
    if poItem.isNull then 
      (
        let nupoItem = PurchaseOrderItem.Create in 
          (
            nupoItem.Quantity:=cItem.Quantity;
            nupoItem.Disc:=cItem.Disc;  
            nupoItem.Subtotal:=cItem.Subtotal;    
            po.PurchaseOrderItem.add(nupoItem); 
            nupoItem --return the newly created purchase order item
          )
      )
      else
        (
          poItem.Quantity := cItem.Quantity;
          poItem.Subtotal:= cItem.Subtotal;
          poItem.Disc = cItem.Disc; 
          poItem -- return the updated purchase order items
        ) 
      endif
  );
  po 
)```




If you find yourself having to similar structures like this (PurchaseOrderItem and ContractItem) that share a lot of property names - it is a candidate for the DuckTyping approach offered by the Transform operator (https://wiki.mdriven.net/Documentation:OCLOperators_transform)
It may make it easier to maintain code when new properties are added to ContractItem and PurchaseOrderItem

I think you have missed to associate the product to the PurchaseOrderItem in the code above?

Would the purpose of this association be to pick attributes that only for the products class that you'd want to add to the PurchaseOrderItem link class?
